# Docker: setctty operation not permitted

Tags: docker

Failed to find any information about the "setctty" operation.

Sometimes when starting a new container I get this error:

```
Error response from daemon:
    Cannot start container dc3e40bc49b6305edca42537d3d7af8b20e6e119d1ea74b473bb5c069f461641:
    setctty operation not permitted
```

Here is the docker info:

```
# docker --debug info
Containers: 2
Images: 501
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-8:3-10224046-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Data file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Data Space Used: 73.16 GB
 Data Space Total: 429.5 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 66.57 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 10.74 GB
 Library Version: 1.02.89-RHEL6 (2014-09-01)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64
Operating System: <unknown>
Debug mode (server): false
Debug mode (client): true
Fds: 19
Goroutines: 17
EventsListeners: 0
```

How to fix this issue or where can I find the info about the "setctty"?

Comment: Can you specify when exactly you get this error? (Referring to "sometimes".)

Comment: We have a script that creates a docker containers for testing purposes. So it creates a containers approximately once an hour.

And ("sometimes") once a few day, our tests alert us about this problem.

Comment: There is not any ubusual:


    docker run -d --dns-search=blablabla -h host.net -t -i registry_ip:port/image/name